# Raspberry Pi 3B+ crystal oscillator - How accurate is it?

Tags: crystal-reports, kernel, raspberry-pi3

I have developed a spectrum analyzer driver using the kernel of the RPi where every time I sample the data, I sample the time, too. The results I received are pretty good but a little bit inconsistent (both in frequency and amplitude estimation). 
When I compared the samples I received out of the accurate wave generator I used, I figured out that even though I generated the same signal with the same frequency - I sampled a signal with small variations in frequency.
I guess the problem comes from the crystal oscillator which is not accurate (due to temperature variations?). can anyone confirm if that is the problem? If so, any idea what alternative do I have? Such as TCXO I can use and etc.
Thanks!

Comment: Can the crystal-reports tag be removed? Crystal Reports is an enterprise reporting platform and not relevant to this question.

Comment: Although I can't answer your question directly, I thought this architecture reference was useful in helping to get to an answer: https://elinux.org/The_Undocumented_Pi

Comment: I have used GPS/PPS to sync time. My frequency error is about 5 PPM. Sudden temerature changes can instantly cause  high shifts is clock frequency.